# vaStacks in java about PushAtBottom Method();

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
//To push an element at the bottom of a stack
public class StackProblem1 {
    public static void pushAtBottom(Stack<Integer> s, int data) {
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            s.push(data);
            return;
        }
        int temp = s.pop();
        pushAtBottom(s, data);
        s.push(temp);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        pushAtBottom(stack, 4);

        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

I have a doubt about the `pushAtBottom` method. `pushAtBottom` is being recursively called inside the method so all the elements will be popped out until stack is empty and new data will be added but when you call the function recursively the temp values are been stored separately like for 1 separately and for 2 and 3 wont it get override and when you call the method recursively how temp variable will be stored.... will it first empty the whole stack and after adding new data it will add temp values or it will do one by one like shifting the new value and adding temp values?

I'm beginner i have understood the concept a little bit but I want to know in depth so I can get more clarification

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't tag unrelated languages.

Comment: `temp` is a local variable, which will reside in the current stack frame. Each stack frame holds it's local variables.